# Unlocking tables if thread is lost

Tags: mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html

The following is the extract from the documentation.

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES real_table WRITE, temp_table WRITE;
mysql> INSERT INTO real_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;
mysql> DELETE FROM temp_table;
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
```

My question is that if I use this logic in the shell script code, and if the thread is lost (not killed) before it reaches "unlock tables" statement, how will I know that some tables are locked and how do I unlock tables manually?

Comment: Have you considered using a transaction instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226766/mysql-transactions-vs-locking-tables

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> how will I know that some tables are locked?

You can use [SHOW OPEN TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-open-tables.html) command to view locked tables.

> how do I unlock tables manually?

If you know the session ID that locked tables - 'SELECT CONNECTION_ID()', then you can run [KILL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/kill.html) command to terminate session and unlock tables.

Comment: if I do not know the session ID and the terminal that locked table is not open, then?

Comment: Try to set WAIT_TIMEOUT period before the locking tables (e.g. SET WAIT_TIMEOUT = 120;). It will help to close that connection automatically after the specified period.

Comment: Not so versatile approach.

Answer (score 168):

Here's what i do to FORCE UNLOCK FOR some locked tables in MySQL

1) Enter MySQL

```
mysql -u your_user -p
```

2) Let's see the list of locked tables

```
mysql> show open tables where in_use>0;
```

3) Let's see the list of the current processes, one of them is locking your table(s)

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

4) Let's kill one of these processes

```
mysql> kill put_process_id_here;
```

Comment: Somehow I've managed to get a table locked, without anything being shown in the processlist (besides sleeping connections)...

Comment: If your process is missing entirely but you are getting complaints about locked tables: just restart mysqld. For me, it was "service mysqld restart"

Comment: After I killed a specific pid, for some reason, processlist becomes empty

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: This is the perfect solution, I'd locked a table thru an crash of my HeidiSQL Client.  I'd expected to need root/SUPER privilege, which I don't have, but this worked without any raised privilege.

Comment: for example:
open 2 connection, in first connection, connection id is 1, another is 2;
in connection 1 we execute sql:
lock tables test write;
and in connection 2, we can see a table is be locked:
show open tables where in_use > 0 ;
can know a table be locked; but I can not know which proces ID locked it if in diff connection session id; so what can i kill it?

Comment: this is useless without the way how to tell the process id that holds the lock.

Comment: I found that the `Info` column in the processlist would show the query that ended up leaving the table open. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

**With Sequel Pro:**

Restarting the app unlocked my tables. It resets the session connection.

`NOTE: I was doing this for a site on my local machine.`