# Identifying what is making MySQL process use 100% of CPU randomly

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.6, system-administration

At the moment we have a problem where sometimes, for no apparent reason, the CPU use of MySQL process skyrockets to 1000% usage and stays there until we manually restart the mysql service. During that time the webpage performs awfully slow.

There must be something in our shop (built in PrestaShop 1.6) that makes it skyrocket, but when don't know exactly what is it. Is there any way I can keep track of what it might be? That way we might be able to know if there's a malfunctioning module.
Maybe some way to keep a log for every SQL sentence sent and the time it was sent so I can compare it with the server load logs?

Comment: Perhaps you can try checking for deadlocks? See here for a detailed description: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

And here is an useful answer for checking which tables are locked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783636/unlocking-tables-if-thread-is-lost#15508863

Comment: Have you run the `mysqladmin pr -vvv` command to view the current ongoing SQL queries while the CPU churning is ongoing ?

Comment: @RadixSalvilines We will keep that in mind, thank you.

Comment: @nos We didn't, next time it happens i'll make sure to check it out. Thank you.

Comment: The [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) tool provides a lot of insight into the health and utilization of your server. Worth using if you're having performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the config / defines.inc.php file, modify the following lines:

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

By

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

AND

```
define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', false);
```

By

```
define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', true);
```

And reload page.

Regards