# Increment a unique column in every row in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, auto-increment

I'm trying to update a table which contains two columns; `id` and `position`. `id` is unique and automatically increments. `position` is unique but does not automatically increment, and in fact has to be set manually.

I need to alter all rows with a position greater than or equal to `5` (or any other number that I provide) to increment them all by one. This is my code:

```
UPDATE slides 
SET   position = position + 1 
WHERE position >= 5;
```

Unfortunately, it returns the following error:

> Error : Duplicate entry '2' for key 'slides_position_unique'

How do I update all these unique number without causing conflicts as I do so? I've tried a subquery that finds all the updatable rows and returns them in reverse, but it doesn't help.

---

```
CREATE TABLE slides
  (id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   position int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   UNIQUE KEY slides_position_unique (position),
   KEY slides_user_id_foreign (user_id),
   CONSTRAINT slides_user_id_foreign
     FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) )
```

Comment: what the output of `show create table `slides` ?

Comment: Do not put additional information into comments - instead, edit your question and add the new information to the question. I've done it for you this time. Please keep this in mind in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use order by in update. As [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) facts :

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the rows are updated in the order
> that is specified

That would result in :

```
UPDATE slides 
SET   position = position + 1 
WHERE position >= 5
ORDER BY position DESC;
```

This way you update the greater first, then the greater-1, then the greater-2, etc... and the unique index is always freed before being assigned to next row.

Note that, depending on your use case, you might want to use row or [table locking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4227957/1278479) to avoid race conditions if other script need to access this data at the same time.

Comment: Exact same problem; THIS is the solution -- thank you! People should upvote this, and OP should accept it as the right one

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the unique constraint -- during the update the values are not unique. You could do it in transaction or drop the constraint and then add it:

```
ALTER TABLE slides DROP index slides_position_unique;
UPDATE slides SET position = position + 1 WHERE position >= 1;
ALTER TABLE slides ADD CONSTRAINT  slides_position_unique UNIQUE (position);
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com#!9/66e0d8 for working example.

Comment: Jesus. That's a very good point, it's entirely possible that the person that told me to do the weird nesting was, in fact, wrong.

Comment: Looking at the CREATE statement I see you have the UNIQUE constraint on position. I would think that the UPDATE will create duplicates in the position column. Check this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com#!9/fe46ee/1 and you can see that the update works as intended on simple input data.

Comment: Would you suggest removing the unique flag and simply ensuring it is unique in the software?

Comment: I think it's best to remove it before the update and then add it immediately after. I think that if the date were consistent before the update, they will also be after the update -- the problem is that during the update, there are some duplicate values.

Comment: Having tested the code without that, it seems to function correctly. I imagine I'll need to lock the table for writing, though, when doing the update, since it's pretty messy if it gets interrupted.

Comment: Just wrap the SQL code in START TRANSACTION;  COMMIT;, this will make sure the database integrity is preserved. Unfortunately, in MySQL you cannot set constraint checking to DEFERRED -- were that possible, you wouldn't have to drop and add the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: applying this query gave duplicate rows. To avoid that change your query. I suppose that means either removing `WHERE position >= 1` (to update all rows), or to add another condition to exclude `slides.position < 1`.

Maybe this more simple query works for you:

```
UPDATE slides 
SET   position = position + 1 
WHERE position >= 1 AND position IS NOT NULL
```

You may probably use `UPDATE IGNORE slides set position = position+1` but this can make you loose some rows.

Comment: This returns the same error. I also tried, to experiment, with removing `WHERE position >= 1`, to no avail.

Comment: so maybe some of your datas are not valid. Is position type = `int`  and `null` forbidden? I just edited my answer to exclude invalid position too. Otherwise, if you are ok to potentially loose some incoherent datas, you can can try `update ignore`

Comment: Null is forbidden, yes. It's just `int`. I'm very confused by the issue.